# How to add images to Tabhost

Tags: android, android-style-tabhost

I want to add background images for Tabhost which i already added in selector xml. But not sure how to add resource while initiating Tab. Below is tab :

Code to add :
getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tabicon)

```
/* Tabs */
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;
        Intent intent;

        // First Activity
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, InfoListView.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("some_things").setIndicator("Info").setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        // Second Activity
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, LogListView.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("top_things").setIndicator("Sync Log").setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height = 95;
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().height = 95;
        /* Tabs ends */
```

Comment: I have updated my ans it will work

Answer (score 0):

Create a `TextView` , set text to that textView, set background drawable to it, and set this textview as `indicator`

Comment: example ? How can i create TextView inside TabHost ?

Comment: See the next answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat like this:

```
TextView mTv = new TextView(mContext);
mTv.setText(/*Your-text*/);
mTv.setBackgroundDrawable(mContext.getResources.getDrawable(/*id-of-your-image*/));
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("top_things").setIndicator(mTv).setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Answer (score 0):

After your tabhost is intilize with indicator and other things add background to it like this

```
 tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tabicon); //fro first tab 
 tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tabicon); //for second tab
```

Comment: Shakeeb...I am putting screenshot of how it is coming. It is not coming properly. Looks like as we are setting icon and not background image...Is this right way to do ? Please see screenshot on my question